# jQuery animation chaining

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have an image that I want to start not visible, then at some point be made visible and THEN have its opacity reduced to .5 over a duration of 2 seconds.
Here is the code that I have for when I want that to happen:

```
  $("#image").removeClass("notVisible").addClass("visible").animate({
                    opacity: 0.5,
                  }, 2000);
```

My problem is that with the code as it is, the image becomes visible directly to an opacity of .5 but what I want is the image to become visible (at normal opacity of 1) and only then be animated to opacity .5
Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 0):

The `.fadeTo()` method animates the opacity of the matched elements.

Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower animations, not faster ones. The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds, respectively. If any other string is supplied, the default duration of 400 milliseconds is used. Unlike the other effect methods, .fadeTo() requires that duration be explicitly specified.

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).fadeTo( "slow" , 0.5, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Source : https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

In your case :

```
$("#image").removeClass("notVisible").addClass("visible").fadeTo( 2000 , 0.5)
```

And set #image opacity to 1 in css.

There is also a great JsFiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/FLMp8/26/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set your element with an initial display of `none` first add add the class `visible` and then remove the `notVisible` class, so to make it obvious. Because by removing the `notVisible` class first, will display the element immediately.

```js
$("#image").addClass("visible").removeClass("notVisible").animate({
                opacity: 0.5,
              }, 2000);
```

```css
.notVisible{
 display: none;
}
.visible{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="notVisible" id="image" style="background:red;width:50px;height:50px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var y = setInterval(function(){
    $("#myElem").css('display', 'block').fadeTo(2000, 0.5);
    clearInterval(y);
  },2000);
});
```

```css
#myElem{
display: none;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myElem"></div>
```

You said you wanted the element to start off non-visible, which I did. Then, 2 seconds later, it appears and then immediately starts to disappear in a matter of 2 seconds, like you asked for.